# Same style for child as parent in tree

Tags: tikz-pgf, trees

I am trying to create a tree in which the child nodes have the same appearance as their parent but I keep getting an unknown error when adding a child and attempting to use the same style:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{x11names}{xcolor}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
[nonLeaf/.style n args={4}{minimum size=8mm, draw,  line width=3pt, draw=MediumPurple3, fill=yellow, text=Blue4, rectangle, label={[align=left, xshift=-5pt]left:{$\alpha:#1$\\$\beta:#2$}}, label={[align=left]right:{$\alpha:#3$\\$\beta:#4$}}},
every child node/.style={nonLeaf}]

\node[nonLeaf={1}{2}{3}{4}]{19};
    %child{node[nonleaf={5}{6}{7}{8}]{25}} <----- problem

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `every child node/.style={nonLeaf}` doesn't make sense if you've defined `nonLeaf` to require 4 arguments. Just delete this and keep `nonLeaf={}{}{}{}` in the child as you have in the commented bit.